# Add download pdf button in popup view in suitecrm

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

Is it possible to add a custom button that downloads pdf ?
ive tried doing it but i only get create button from this example: [Link here](https://community.sugarcrm.com/thread/18317)

```
'searchInputs' => array(
        1 => 'payment_date',
        2 => 'payment_stage',
        3 => 'or_no',
    ),
    'create' =>
        array(
            'formBase' => 'PrintPayment.php',
            'formBaseClass' => 'PrintPayment',
            'getFormBodyParams' => array('', '', 'PrintPaymentSave'),
            'createButton' => $mod_strings['LNK_NEW_PAYMENT']

        ),
```

is there any other way to add a download functionality ?

```
<?php
if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');
require_once('include/SugarObjects/forms/FormBase.php');

class PrintPayment extends FormBase {

    var $moduleName = 'PrintPayment';
    var $objectName = 'PrintPayment';

    function handleSave($prefix, $redirect=true, $useRequired=false){
        require_once('include/formbase.php');
        $focus = new PrintPayment();
        $focus = populateFromPost($prefix, $focus);
        $focus->save();

    }
}
```

is there any experts who knows this ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to go to dropdown editor in admin panel and find "pdf_template_type_dom".
It's list responsible for modules available in PDF - templates module.

After adding module of your choice to the list you might need to rebuild the app.

After you add module, create a some template for it.

Afterwards you need to modify your viewdefs in your module to add the button allowing for PDF print. Here is custom code for the button:

```
array ( 'customCode' => '<input type="button" class="button" onClick="showPopup(\'pdf\');" value="PDF">'
```

Add the button somewhere and voila.
I tested in DetailView for my custom modules but the principle should be the same.

Comment: Thank you so much man. Ive been scratching my head in this problem for quite some time now.

Comment: tried it but it only works on detailview when i do the same for popupview it doesn't work :/